# How to get key from multiple values in python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
dictionary={'John':['facebook',linkedin,instagram]}
c1=input("Enter the app:")
   for k,v in dictionary.items():
     if c1==v:
      print(k)
```

*Here I want to search an app like linkedin have access to which all users but getting nothing in the output. Can someone advise ?*

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` because it is a list of apps:

```
if c1 in v:
    print(k)
```